# how to show one random background color for each record in a html table

Tags: html, css, angular

I am using angular version 8. In my application i have to show a random color for each record in html table. but when displaying the random color if i move the cursor in display page, for each movement the color changing and i am seeing a lot of new colors for single record.
Can any one suggest that how to show one random color for one record in html table.

here is my code..

```js
getRandomColor() {
      let letters = '0123456789ABCDEF';
      let color = '#';
      for (let i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        color += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * 16)];
      }
      const styles = {
        'background-color' : color,
        'padding':"27px",
        "border-radius":"100%",
        "color":"white"
      };
      return styles;
    }
```

```html
 <span  [ngStyle]="getRandomColor()">V</span>
```

Comment: You code works for me, can it is you real code, if not, can you share you code for help you??

Comment: @ReynierAlbertoRiveroAlarcón, on display page if you move ur cursor, colors changing or only one color is displaying

Comment: each row is a different color, and does not change, unless you refresh the browser tab

Answer (score 1):

It's happening, because Angular runs change detection each time you move your mouse. When change detection happens, Angular executes all functions which are bound in the template.

For this reason (performance bottleneck), it is not recommended to bind functions to templates. You can read more about it [here](https://dzone.com/articles/why-we-shound-not-use-function-inside-angular-temp) and [here](https://medium.com/showpad-engineering/why-you-should-never-use-function-calls-in-angular-template-expressions-e1a50f9c0496).

Now for the actual solution, here is a description of the approach.

*Because it is not a quick solution, I cannot post the full code here, so you will need to use these suggestions to do the implementation. If you are stuck somewhere or don't know some of the points (e.g. how to create a pipe), post separate questions or search.*

Instead of generating a random colour, the idea would be to generate a colour for each cell based on a value in the table cell. This way, you can use a pipe to get the colour code based on a specific input:

1. Instead of `[ngStyle]="getRandomColor()"` you would do something like this: `[style.background]="cellValue | getRandomColor"`.

Here, `cellValue` would be the actual cell value (or it can also be a row number or any other predefined value you have available), and `getRandomColor` is the pipe you need to create.

2. Create the pipe. The logic for the pipe can be adopted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16348977/1433107).

This way, the background colour would be set based on the value of the cell. And you will not run into the change detection issue as you have now.

Comment: maby disable the change detection in component works

Comment: @ReynierAlbertoRiveroAlarcón If you set change detection to `onPush` it won't help with the issue described in the OP. `onPush` limits the change detection based on inputs.