# Convert RGB to Hexadecimal

Tags: java, colors, hex

If I have a `Color` object, how can I convert it's RGB values to a hexadecimal integer? I've been searching for ages, and all I've found are "Hexadecimal to RGB", or it doesn't return an Integer value, or something else that I don't want.

I want it to return the hexadecimal as an `int` value, not a string, or anything else. Can anyone help?

Here is my code where I need to convert a colour to hex, using someone's answer to try to convert it:

```
public static void loadImageGraphics(BufferedImage image, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    for(int yy = 0; yy < height; yy++) {
        for(int xx = 0; xx < width; xx++) {
            Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(xx, yy));
            pixels[x + y * width] = c.getRed() * (0xFF)^2 + c.getGreen() * 0xFF + c.getBlue();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: An integer is just a value. It only becomes a hexadecimal representation when you convert it to a string.

Comment: Other solutions here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/how-to-convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-an-hexadecimal-value-in-java

Comment: String hexColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", 158, 255, 168);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This utility function is working fine for me:

```
public static String convertColorToHexadeimal(Color color)
{
        String hex = Integer.toHexString(color.getRGB() & 0xffffff);
        if(hex.length() < 6) 
        {
            if(hex.length()==5)
                hex = "0" + hex;
            if(hex.length()==4)
                hex = "00" + hex;
            if(hex.length()==3)
                hex = "000" + hex;
        }
        hex = "#" + hex;
        return hex;
}
```

Comment: This returns a string. I tried to add a `Integer.parseInt()`, but I get a `NumberFormatException`.

Comment: @sparklyllama: You can *write* an integer in base-16, just like `0xffffff` is `16777215`.

Comment: Color c = Color.RED;
String hex = convertColorToHexadeimal(c);
System.out.println("hex:"+hex);
String hexRed   = hex.substring(0, 2);
String hexGreen = hex.substring(2, 4);
String hexBlue  = hex.substring(4, 6);
        
System.out.println(convert(hexRed));
System.out.println(convert(hexGreen));
System.out.println(convert(hexBlue));

public static int convert(String n) 
{
   return Integer.valueOf(n, 16);
}

Comment: Actually, I'm getting a `NumberFormatException` in the `convert` method.

Comment: You can use smart line of code -> String hexColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", 158, 255, 168);

Answer (score 0):

You can use this smart line of code.

String hexColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", 158, 255, 168);

String hexColor = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", R, G, B);