# How to loop a 8*1 svg image(generated by java) to get a 8*8 svg image?

Tags: java, svg

```
import java.util.Random;

class svg{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String f="\""; //use f to stand for \" in order to avoid confusing when writing svg codes.
        System.out.format("<?xml version=%s1.0%s standalone=%sno%s?>\n", f,f,f,f);
        System.out.format("<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC %s-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN%s\n%shttp://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%s>\n",f,f,f,f);
        System.out.format("<svg height=%s800%s width=%s800%s xmlns=%shttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg%s version=%s1.1%s>\n",f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f);
        verticleAliens();
        System.out.println("</svg>");
    }



    public static void verticleAliens(){
        String f="\"";
        for(int i=0; i<=800; i+=100){
            String randomColor1 = color();
            String randomColor2 = color();
            String randomColor3 = color();
            String randomColor4 = color();
            String randomColor5 = color();
            String randomColor6 = color();
            String randomColor7 = color();

            System.out.format("<circle cx=%s50%s cy=%s%d%s r=%s20%s stroke=%s"+randomColor1+"%s stroke-width=%s3%s fill=%s"+randomColor2+"%s />\n", f,f,f,60+i,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f,f);
            System.out.format("<line x1=%s50%s y1=%s%d%s x2=%s50%s y2=%s%d%s stroke=%s"+randomColor3+"%s stroke-width=%s5%s />\n", f,f,f,50+i,f,f,f,f,30+i,f,f,f,f,f);
            System.out.format("<line x1=%s40%s y1=%s%d%s x2=%s20%s y2=%s%d%s stroke=%s"+randomColor4+"%s stroke-width=%s3%s />\n", f,f,f,60+i,f,f,f,f,50+i,f,f,f,f,f);
            System.out.format("<circle cx=%s36%s cy=%s%d%s r=%s3%s fill=%s"+randomColor5+"%s />\n", f,f,f,15+i,f,f,f,f,f);
            System.out.format("<rect x=%s40%s y=%s%d%s width=%s20%s height=%s20%s style=%sfill:"+randomColor6+";stroke-width:3;stroke:"+randomColor7+"%s/>\n\n",f,f,f,10+i,f,f,f,f,f,f,f);
        }
    }

    public static String color(){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int r = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        int g = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        int b = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x",r,g,b);
    }
}
```

These Java codes can generate a svg image which has 8 different "aliens" in a row, here is the image:

[image]

As you can, this svg picture has 8*1 different aliens. But I want to get a 8*8 aliens svg image(aliens should have same color patterns horizontally). How can I write loops to achieve that(Or, how can I modify my for loop)? Thank you!

NOTE:If you want to try these codes on your computer, you can use `java svg>aliens.svg` to generate a svg file which names

> aliens.svg

after you compile the program. Then open it in a browser.

Comment: how about two nested loops? the outer one for the rows, the inner one for the columns. only at the begin of the outer loop, you define the colors, so every alien in a row will look the same

Comment: Wow thank you!!!I've fixed that!

Comment: always glad to help. perhaps you can post the fixed code as answer so the question gets solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Manuel_Jain gives me a very helpful advice that I can write two nested loops to fix my problem. Here is the updated code:

```
import java.util.Random;

class svg{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //use slashQuote to stand for \" in order to avoid confusing when modifying svg codes.
        String slashQuote="\"";
        System.out.format("<?xml version=%s1.0%s standalone=%sno%s?>\n", 
            slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
        System.out.format("<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC %s-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN%s\n%shttp://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd%s>\n",
            slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
        System.out.format("<svg height=%s800%s width=%s800%s xmlns=%shttp://www.w3.org/2000/svg%s version=%s1.1%s>\n",
            slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
        aliens();
        System.out.println("</svg>");
    }


    //Most of works were done in this function. It prints all aliens.
    public static void aliens(){
        //use slashQuote to stand for \" in order to avoid confusing when modifying svg codes.
        String slashQuote="\"";

        //This loop generates different aliens (because of randomColor) verticlely. It is looping 1*8 aliens to get 8*8 aliens. 
        for(int i=0; i<=800; i+=100){

            //get 7 colors by calling color() function for 7 times. The number is 7 because there will be 7 different color in one alien.
            String randomColor1 = color();
            String randomColor2 = color();
            String randomColor3 = color();
            String randomColor4 = color();
            String randomColor5 = color();
            String randomColor6 = color();
            String randomColor7 = color();

            //This loop generates identicle aliens horizontaly. It is looping a 1*1 alien to get 1*8 aliens.
            //It will not affected by "String randomColorN = color();" because I only defined colors in outer loop.
            for(int j=0;j<=800;j+=100){
                //Here is my alien!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
                System.out.format("<ellipse cx=%s%d%s cy=%s%d%s rx=%s10%s ry=%s30%s stroke=%s"+randomColor1+
                    "%s stroke-width=%s3%s fill=%s"+randomColor2+"%s />\n", 
                    slashQuote,50+j,slashQuote,slashQuote,60+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,
                    slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);

                System.out.format("<line x1=%s%d%s y1=%s%d%s x2=%s%d%s y2=%s%d%s stroke=%s"+randomColor3+
                    "%s stroke-width=%s5%s />\n", 
                    slashQuote,50+j,slashQuote,slashQuote,50+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,50+j,slashQuote,
                    slashQuote,30+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);

                System.out.format("<line x1=%s%d%s y1=%s%d%s x2=%s%d%s y2=%s%d%s stroke=%s"+randomColor4+
                    "%s stroke-width=%s3%s />\n", 
                    slashQuote,40+j,slashQuote,slashQuote,60+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,20+j,slashQuote,
                    slashQuote,50+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
                System.out.format("<circle cx=%s%d%s cy=%s%d%s r=%s3%s fill=%s"+randomColor5+"%s />\n", 
                    slashQuote,36+j,slashQuote,slashQuote,15+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
                System.out.format("<rect x=%s%d%s y=%s%d%s width=%s20%s height=%s20%s style=%sfill:"+randomColor6+
                    ";stroke-width:3;stroke:"+randomColor7+"%s/>\n\n",
                    slashQuote,40+j,slashQuote,slashQuote,10+i,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote,
                    slashQuote,slashQuote,slashQuote);
            }
        }
    }

    //Generate a random number.
    public static String color(){
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int r = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        int g = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        int b = randomGenerator.nextInt(256);
        /*#%02x%02x%02x converts the RGB color to the hexadecimal value. I tried to use RGB color at first 
        but it doesn't work in svg. Then I found this method in stack overflow. Here is the link: 
        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/how-to-convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-an-hexadecimal-value-in-java*/
        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x",r,g,b);
    }
}
```

BTW, here is the new svg picture:
[image]

Thank you, @Manuel_Jain!