# AmbilWarna color picker with RGB entry?

Tags: android, color-picker

I'm currently using, and like, the AmbilWarna color picker (https://github.com/yukuku/ambilwarna).  But it would be nice to have the option to enter colours via an RGB entry field.  I can't see that this is possible, but maybe I've missed something?

Answer (score 0):

Im not familiar with that library but you could create your own prompt and have the user enter the rgb values themselves and then convert to hex. You could also have a view which displays the currently selected color when the user changes the value. Heres a method to convert rgb to hex.

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

[Convert a RGB Color Value to a Hexadecimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/how-to-convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-an-hexadecimal-value-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for a great new android color picker that use material design I have forked an great project from github and made a simple-to-use android color picker dialog.

This is the project: [Android Color Picker](https://github.com/Pes8/android-material-color-picker-dialog)