# set RGB color of text view programmatically

Tags: android, colors, textview, rgb

I am getting rgba color from api "color": rgba(59,28,28,0.47). Can any one tell me how can i set this color in text view?

In api i get random values for colors sometimes it is in hex code and sometimes RGB. I have no idea about RGB , please suggest.

Comment: what do you mean by `rub`?

Comment: rgb sorry auto correct

Comment: text.setTextColor(Color.argb(0,200,0,0)); Only int value.

Comment: Follow this link (see answer by -@Vivien Barousse)- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607858/convert-a-rgb-color-value-to-a-hexadecimal