# Javascript - getting RGB color from a string

Tags: javascript, string, algorithm

In my application I have a chat service.

And as with chat, there are many users with different nicks, and I would like to have each nick with different color. So, are there any javascript algorithms which can convert a string (nick) to a RGB value? I was thinking about, idk, getting ascii value of each character, adding them together, and then somehow converting it to three hex values? Or something similar? Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach it?

Comment: _"I was thinking about, idk, getting ascii value of each character..."_ - So why don't you try that?

Comment: @nnnnnn: Because maybe someone already implemented something similar, and is willing to share his solution with me?

Comment: Looks like a [number](https://www.google.com/search?q=generate+RGB+based+on+string) of [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426404/create-a-hexadecimal-colour-based-on-a-string-with-jquery-javascript) [people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464745/compute-hex-color-code-for-an-arbitrary-string) have done exactly what you describe. Try something out, like @nnnnnn said, or do some research you oldbie (said as lovingly as possible)!!

Comment: @admdrew: Yeah, there are some solutions there, thanks!