# Compute hex color code for an arbitrary string in Objective c ios 7

Tags: objective-c, random, colors, hex

I need to assign user profiles colors in a pseudo random consistent way based on their username/name/any string.

How do I do this in objective C iOS 7?

Java based example is here

[Compute hex color code for an arbitrary string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464745/compute-hex-color-code-for-an-arbitrary-string)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are probably many ways. Here's one:

```
NSString *someString = ... // some string to "convert" to a color
NSInteger hash = someString.hash;
int red = (hash >> 16) & 0xFF;
int green = (hash >> 8) & 0xFF;
int blue = hash & 0xFF;
UIColor *someColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red / 255.0 green:green / 255.0 blue:blue / 255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

The same string will always give the same color. Different strings will generally give different colors but it is possible that two different strings could give the same color.

Answer (score 0):

My version:

```
+ (UIColor *)colorForString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSUInteger hash = string.hash;

    CGFloat hue = ( hash % 256 / 256.0 );  //  0.0 to 1.0
    CGFloat saturation = ( hash % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from white
    CGFloat brightness = ( hash % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;  //  0.5 to 1.0, away from black

    return [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
}
```

It creates more saturated but bright enough and beautiful colors.